# Find records either with no association or where association attribute value !=?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have a simple association like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :photos
end

class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user

   # Photo fields => id, image, photo_type
end
```

In the photo model `photo_type` value can be in 'personal', family' or 'official'.

What is the best way to get all users either have NO photos OR photo_type != 'personal'(if the user has photos)?

I'd appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I've flagged a duplicate which has lots of answers, but in a nutshell, you could use:

```
# No photos
User.includes(:photos).where( photos: { user_id: nil } )
# Not personal
User.includes(:photos).where.not( photos: { photo_type: "personal" } )

# Users with photos, where the `photo_type` isn't "personal"
User.includes(:photos).where.not( photos: { user_id: nil, photo_type: "personal" } )
```

There's also a Rails 5 approach that avoids loading the association, though I've not used yet personally:

```
User.left_outer_joins(:photos).where.not( photos: { user_id: nil, photo_type: "personal" } )
```

How does that look? The last option do what you're after?

Let me know if you've any questions.

Comment: okay just tried +1

Comment: Did this help at all @RakeshPatidar?